# MODIS AQUA Data - Stacking / Mosaic data with python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

Is there a way to use the GEO data contained in a HDF4 file so one could look at the same area over many years?

Hence, can an area be cut out of the data and how?

I plotted MODIS Data and as you can see below the river moves downwards (rectangular structure top left corner). So over a whole year it's not the same location that I'm observing.

[image: MODIS data]

There's a directory in the subdatasets called Geolocation Fields with Long and Alt directories. So is it possible to access this information or lay it over the data to cut out a specific area?

For example, If we take a look at the NASA picture below would it be possible to cut it between 10-15 alt. and -5 to 0 long.

[image: Nasa pic]

You can download a sample file by copying the url below:

https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2009/034/MYD021KM.A2009034.1345.006.2012058160107.hdf